# Compute the curvature of a curve on a sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

In an exercise made of various points, I've proved that $\alpha(u) = (-\cos^2(u),-\sin(u)\cos(u),-\sin(u))  $ united with the equator of the unit sphere gives the intersection between the sphere and a Moebius strip (with a certain parametrization).

Now I'm asked to compute the curvature of the $\alpha$ curve, and to check if it's equal to $0$ in any points.

The thing I'm sure of is that $k(\alpha)$ could never be $0$, or $\alpha$ would be a line for some part of it. But I couldn't compute it: since $|\alpha'|=\sqrt{1+\cos^2(u)}$, its' impossible to parametrize it by arc lenght. I've tried to use the formula $$\frac{|\alpha'\times\alpha''|}{|\alpha'|^3}$$
but the computation gets hard, so it made me think that there could be something of easier use.

Comment: A sphere has constant curvature so if a curve is contained on a sphere then ...?

Comment: The sphere has constant gaussian curvature (K=1/R, if R is the radius) but what's the relationship with the curvature of a curve..?

Comment: $k=\sqrt{k_g^2+1/R^2}\geq1/R>0$; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_curvature

Comment: Is the curve $\alpha(t)=(t,t^3)$ “a line for some part of it”?